# How do you structure a recursive function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, recursion, python-3.4

I'm trying to create a recursive function that checks if a grade can be converted to a float, then checks to make sure the grade is between 0 and 100. My logic as to why this would work is:

1. Checks to see if the grade can be converted to a float.
2. If it can't be converted into a float, the user receives an error message, has to input a new grade, and gradeChecker checks again.
3. If it can be converted into a float, gradeChecker checks to see if it's between 0 and 100
4. If the grade between 0 and 100, the grade is then appended to the Assignments dictionary.
5. If the grade isn't between 0 and 100, the user gives a new grade, which is passed back in to the function, so repeat starting at step 1.

Can you tell me how this code doesn't follow that logic?

```
def gradeChecker(grade):
    while True:
        try:
            grade = float(grade)        
            while (grade < 0) or (grade > 100):
                print("Sorry, your grade must be between 0 and 100.")
                grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
                gradeChecker(grade)
        except:
            print("Sorry, that's an invalid input. Please only use numbers and decimal points!")
            grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
        else:
            break
    Assignments[assignment].append(grade)
```

Edit: Indentations fixed!

For reference, here is the entirety of the code I am using to pass grade into gradeChecker.

```
import collections #We import collections so we can use an ordered dictionary
Assignments = collections.OrderedDict() #We create an ordered dictionary called 'Assignments'
#We have to add each assignment to our dictionary individually because it's an ordered dictionary
#You can't convert a regular dictionary, which is unordered, to an ordered dictionary
#If you used a regular dictionary, when looping through the assignments they would be displayed at random
Assignments['Exam 1'] = [0.2] #We add the assignment and the weight to the dictionary
Assignments['Exam 2'] = [0.2] #We add the assignment and the weight to the dictionary
Assignments['Exam 3'] = [0.2] #We add the assignment and the weight to the dictionary
Assignments['Homework'] = [0.2] #We add the assignment and the weight to the dictionary
Assignments['LQR'] = [0.1] #We add the assignment and the weight to the dictionary
Assignments['Final'] = [0.1] #We add the assignment and the weight to the dictionary

#We have to define our grade checker before it is called so that it can be used to verify users inputs

def gradeChecker(grade): #Used to verify that a users grades are in-between 0 and 100
    while True:
        try:
            grade = float(grade)        
            while (grade < 0) or (grade > 100):
                print("Sorry, your grade must be between 0 and 100.")
                grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
                gradeChecker(grade)
        except:
            print("Sorry, that's an invalid input. Please only use numbers and decimal points!")
            grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
        else:
            break
    Assignments[assignment].append(grade) #We append the grade to the assignment to be used with it's weight for the final grade calculation

#INPUT

for assignment in Assignments.keys(): #We loop through every assignment in our  Assignments dictionary
    grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment) #We ask the user to enter their grade
    gradeChecker(grade) #We check to see if their grade is valid by passing their input through the gradeChecker function
```

Comment: You should review your indentation. What is Assignments exactly ?

Comment: every grade, regardless if valid or not, will be appended to the list, which i don't think is your intent

Comment: and since grade never changes inside of each call, your while loop will never break if the user inputs something wrong. I suggest taking that while loop out (since youre doing recursive calls anyways) and put the append in your else block

Comment: If you're not willing to take the time to get the indentation right in the question, why should we take the time to answer the question? Indentation is a critical part of python syntax.

Comment: @Alex, I added more context to the question!

Comment: @RNar, Can you explain how they'll all be added to the list? I thought by doing it this way, they'll only be appended once the loop breaks, which should happen once the users input for grade is valid.

Comment: @BryanOakley, it was correct inside my code, but StackOverflow broke my formatting. I went through and re-indented everything in my question so it's 'proper' on SO. It was already proper in my code.

Comment: The idea behind this function (i.e., using _both_ loop _and_ recursion for the try-again logic) is strange. Care to explain why you want to make the function recursive?

Comment: @Ian, look at my post for code that SHOULD (no guarantees) work. Remember that recursive calls create a tree of calls, which means that once one of the calls finish, it will attempt to finish the calls below. In this case, since you are never actually changing the value of `grade`, the while loop outcome (ie, the try/except/else block), which depends on grade, will never change, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @Helgi, the purpose of gradeChecker is to determine if the value is a float (or can be converted to a float) and if so, if it's between 0 and 100. The issue I'm having is once I've determined it's a float, I need to check if it's between 0 and 100, but if it's not the user has to re-enter their grade. I then have to re-verify that their grade is a float, and go back to checking if it's between 0 and 100!

Comment: @Ian, so no need to make it recursive, right? R Nar is right, recursion is best avoided here. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both recursion and loop here is redundant. Moreover, loops should be preferred to recursion in 'normal' languages like Python (i.e., not Lisp) unless you're dealing with an inherently recursive data structure like a tree.

Given that you never stated *why* you need to use recursion in the first place, I suggest to use something like this:

```
def input_grade(assignment):
    while True:
        try:
            grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
            grade = float(grade)
            if grade < 0 or grade > 1000:
                raise ValueError
            return grade
        except:
            print("Sorry, that's an invalid input. Please only use numbers and decimal points!")

for assignment in Assignments:
    Assignments[assignment].append(input_grade(assignment))
```

**Note 1**. I didn't test the code above, but it should give you the general idea of how to structure this function.

**Note 2**. You should avoid modifying `Assignments` in the function, that's an unwanted side effect. Better offload this to the main code.

**Note 3**. Technically, the `try`..`except` in my code is an example of exception-based logic, which isn't a great thing (however, this is way better than using recursion here).

Answer (score 0):

```
def gradeChecker(grade):
    try:
        grade = float(grade)        
        while (grade < 0) or (grade > 100):
            print("Sorry, your grade must be between 0 and 100.")
            grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
            gradeChecker(grade)
    except:
        print("Sorry, that's an invalid input. Please only use numbers and decimal points!")
        grade = input("What grade did you receive on: %s? " % assignment)
    else:
        Assignments[assignment].append(grade)
```

the thing with your code is that it's redundant; the while statement is there to do what you already have the recursive calls doing. imo, the while statement is better since recursion often uses up more memory but thats just an opinion.